# MVC JsonResult not working with chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

i want jquery to take a JsonResult from my MVC controller but it does'nt receive any data!

If I put the output into a textfile and enter its link its working so I think my jQuery is fine.

Then I was testing with other browsers like chrome and I saw NOTHING. The requested page was just emtpy.. no errors. Also IE seems to have problems receiving my string.. only firefox displays the string but why?

```
    public JsonResult jsonLastRequests()
    {
        List<Request> requests = new List<Request>();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            requests.Add(new Models.Request()
            {
                ID = (int)r[0],
                SiteID = r[1].ToString(),
                Lat = r[2].ToString(),
                City = r[4].ToString(),
                CreationTime = (DateTime)r[5]
            });
        }
        r.Close();
        return Json(requests);
    }
```

I found out that also if I want to return the JSON as string its not working!
Its working with a string in all browsers now.. but jQuery is still not loading anything

```
        var url = "http://../jsonLastRequests";
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'ID' },
                { name: 'SiteID' },
                { name: 'Lat' },
                { name: 'CreationTime' },
                { name: 'City' },
            ],
            id: 'id',
            url: url
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
            downloadComplete: function (data, status, xhr) { },
            loadComplete: function (data) { },
            loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { }
        });
```

I fixed my problem  by adding:
access-control-allow-origin:*

Comment: Your code is missing pieces (where is the DataReader, r, coming from?) but assuming this is a trimmed down version, I don't see anything wrong with it...

Comment: Caching problem? Try setting cache: false in your jQuery.ajax call...

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery because I can't see anything im chrome as well

Comment: Does this even compile ? where is "r" declared and populated ?

Comment: Its working with a string in all browsers now.. but jQuery is still not loading anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public HtmlString jsonLastRequests()
    {
        List<Request> requests = new List<Request>();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            requests.Add(new Models.Request()
            {
                ID = (int)r[0],
                SiteID = r[1].ToString(),
                Lat = r[2].ToString(),
                City = r[4].ToString(),
                CreationTime = (DateTime)r[5]
            });
        }  r.Close();
 System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();


            return new HtmlString(jSerializer.Serialize(requests ));}
```

I have done same approch like this

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/home/GetSurvey',
        data: {
            XmlPath: $("#xmlpath").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsonData) {
            jsonStringQuestionaire = jsonData;
            LoadSurvey();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error loading ' + id);
        }
    });
 questionaireJsonList = eval(jsonStringQuestionaire);
```

Comment: I get this error: Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: its a cross browser error good if you make it internal request by passing short url  inplace of "http://../jsonLastRequests" try something  /controller/jsonLastRequests